# Are the classes "ResultSet" and "executeQuery" database-vendor-specific?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I came up with this question when working on establishing a connection between Oracle and JDBC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29) (not a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28software%29#Java)). The idea is that the class implementing the interface will be vendor specific but the interface is common.

Comment: I think i got an answer for my first question. What about "executeQuery" function?. To what extent does the string in the executeQuery function of a statement object have to depend on the database vendor?

Comment: @lamahewa Well, *which type* provides the `executeQuery` function? Is this an interface (that vendors will supply an implementation to) or a class (of which there is already an implementation)? Also, it isn't very practical for a vendor-agnostic method (implementation) to return an instance of a vendor-specific class.

Comment: `executeQuery()` is part of the `Statement` interface. The Statement implementation is vendor specific (like the ResultSet) but it is written to a common interface.